# Can I use a 3x10 shifter/brake lever on a 3x8 bike?

Tags: road-bike, brake-levers

I have a 3x8 road bike, but mistakenly bought a 3x10 Shimano derailleur/brake lever.  Will it work or should I exchange?

Answer (score 5):

No, the cable pull is different between 8 speed and 10 speed. You will need to exchange it.

There is a [detailed explanation here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bicycles/Maintenance_and_Repair/Gear-changing_Dimensions), but the short version is that there are no 8 speed rear derailleurs that are compatible with 10 speed shifters, or vice versa.

Comment: Well...thank you...and Rats!!  I'll exchange, and you saved me probably hours of frustration!